# how to separate uv maps

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I started with one mesh and then separated it later on.
When I now try to paint on one, I paint on both.

How can i separate the uv maps or do something else to prevent that?

thank you for all the tips and ideas.[image]
the head and the body are 2 different objects.
[image]

I know the map isn't very clean. learning to do that these days.

Comment: your 2 UVmaps must not overlay on the Image Texture, otherwise when you'll paint on one part it will also paint on another

Comment: Either pack UV islands on the UV maps so that they don't intersect (comfortable to do when both meshes are part of one object to edit at once or with Mutli-edit option in 2.8) or use 2 separate images

Comment: thank you for the help you two :) is there no way to make it its own uvmap?

Comment: UV map will be shared between meshes of one object. If you separate meshes into different objects you will have different UV maps. Note though that unless you paint on 2 different images this won't necessarily solve the problem - even 2 different objects with different UV maps mapped to one image still can have 
overlapping on paint as UVs still will be mapped to one image

Comment: Are you using the same material on both meshes?

Comment: i was using the same material. i was not aware of it. thank you everyone for your help! i finally know why now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont give the same material to both meshes, since you are painting on the same image it will affect the other one.